# how to work out the case of a segement

Tags: english-to-german, grammatical-case

I'm getting better at working out the case I should use in many sentences but I thought of a sentence like:

> Here is our dog

would `our dog` all be in the accusative case because it is the argument to `is`/`sein`? so if I wrote:

> Hier ist den Hund

I guess that would be correct because `the dog` should be in the accusative here. But when adding the additional info saying it is `our` dog does that change the case to be genative to show ownership, would it be accusative or genative?

> Hier ist unseren Hund

oder

> Hier ist unseres Hund

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not actually right.

**After *sein*, *bleiben* and *werden* we use nominative.**

> Hier ist der Hund.

Adding "our" changes nothing, exactly as in English, you do not say

> <s>Here is our dog's. / Here is our's dog.</s> (Nothing like that)

You just say

> Here is our dog.

In German it would be

> Hier ist unser Hund.

Note the form "unser", which is correct for masculine and neuter, nominative (unser Hund, unser Haus).

More examples for better understanding:

> Er ist mein Onkel.
>
> Ich werde Vater.
>
> Meine Ex-Freundin ist und bleibt eine nervige Zicke.

Comment: The comparison with English does not help much here, because English speakers do not use cases consistently for this, compare ["it's me"](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/it-is-i-versus-it-is-me).

Comment: Although Stephie is right in noting that this was not the question ;)

Answer (score 5):

While Barth is correct on the usage of nominative after sein/bleiben/werden, in your case there is even a simpler explanation:

The *subject* of your sentence is "our dog" -> and the subject is in *nominative*.

Therefore you translate "Here is our dog." to:

> "Hier ist unser Hund."